# Launch a local application when clicking a link

Tags: web-applications, web

I'm developing an internal web application, that allows me to store remote control credentials for my customers. Every time I want to connect to a customers computer, I need to start the remote support software, copy&paste username and password and then hit the "start" button. The software would have command line arguments available, that allow me to start a session immediately, however, I don't know how to start the .exe from within my browser application.

What are the options to launch a local application from a link in a web application?

Comment: This is like iTunes links, I'm interested too.

Comment: Yes, exactly. iTunes or Zune, both have this magic links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to devise a custom protocol for the URLs in your links (e.g. "customprotocol://blahblah") and register your application as an external protocol handler with the OS. This way, when the link is clicked the browser will know to launch the handler; from within that, you can read incoming parameters from the URL and act accordingly.

The procedure for registering such a protocol handler is OS-specific. See [registering an application to a URL protocol on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [registering a protocol on Mozilla KB](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol).